# python function to try/except assigning variables

Tags: python

I want to assign variables like this:

`Title = 'Lord of the Rings'`

The issue here is that the value isn't always available, sometimes the server doesn't respond well and I get error that crashes my code.
And I have a lot of variables to assign.

So I decided to create a function that uses try and except:

```
def try_this(identificator, value):
    try:
       identificator = value
       print(identificator,': ',value)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc

for item in items:
   try_this(ebay_Title,     item.title)
   try_this(ebay_Price,     item.currentPrice.value)
   #etc...
```

Expected behavior:

```
ebay_title  : 'Lord of the rings'
```

Actual behavior:

```
'Lord of the rings' : 'Lord of the rings'
```

Comment: This isn't how variables work in Python. If the name of the variable is important to anyone other than a human reading the code, you should be using a mapping like a `dict` instead: `variables['Title'] = 'Lord of the Rings'`.

Comment: Would it not be better to have the `item` dict pre-populated with empty strings, so they always exist?

Comment: I tried, result is the same

Comment: I think using map() could be the answer, but I can't figure the needed syntax

Comment: In your function, you're only setting a local variable (which initially has the desired variable name in it) It would be easier to pass in a dictionary and see what keys are set within the function,

Comment: I'm curious, what is the error that crashes your code? The only thing I can think of is when a variable hadn't been initialized before, but in your case, is it because the member in `items`  list doesn't have a certain value?

You can check using something like `getattr(item, 'title', None)` where it would be `None` if it doesn't exist within `item`.

Comment: It's a server side error, the actual function I use is a bit more complex: 
`for item in response.reply.searchResult.item:`
And sometimes the server says there's not searchResult in response.reply
The the code crushes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any errors in your code will occur at the point when you try to read `item.title` or `item.currentPrice.value`. So your proposed solution will still crash just *before* calling `try_this`.

When you call a function, Python first computes the values of the arguments, then assigns those values to variables in the function. So Python will try to read `item.title` or `item.currentPrice.value` *before* it calls `try_this`, then it will load `try_this` and assign the value it got to the local `value` variable inside the function. After that, there is no possibility of an error: you can *always* assign `value` to another variable.

So you need to wrap the reference to `item.title` or `item.currentPrice.value` in a `try`/`except` block.

This is the most straightforward way to do that:

```
try:
    ebay_Title = item.title
except:
    # handle error here, e.g., assign a default value
    traceback.print_exc()

try:
    ebay_Price = item.currentPrice.value
except:
    # handle error here, e.g., assign a default value
    traceback.print_exc()
```

As you've seen, this can get tedious. In your case, the error always occurs when you try to read an attribute, so you could write code specifically to handle that:

```
def get_attr(obj, attr_name, default_value=None):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, attr_name)
    except:
        # handle any errors here
        traceback.print_exc()
        return default_value

ebay_Title = get_attr(item, 'title')
# handle missing value (optional)
if ebay_Title is None:
    ...

ebay_Price = get_attr(get_attr(item, 'currentPrice'), 'value')
# handle missing value (optional)
if ebay_Price is None:
    ...
```

Note that `get_attr` is very similar to the built-in `getattr` function, but it will catch any kind of error that occurs when trying to read the attribute, not just missing-attribute errors.

If you don't like the `get_attr(get_attr(item, 'currentPrice'), 'value')` syntax, you could have `get_attr` accept a dot-separated attribute list like this:

```
def get_attr(obj, attr_name, default_value=None):
    try:
        val = obj
        for attr in attr_name.split('.'):
            val = getattr(val, attr)
        return val
    except:
        # handle any errors here
        traceback.print_exc()
        return default_value

ebay_Title = get_attr(item, 'title')
ebay_Price = get_attr(item, 'currentPrice.value')
```

Comment: Wow this is definitely a great answer. I will try your code, probably this is the more helpful answer of all, and the best explained. Now I understand  the problem and the solution as well, thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

As said before, you really don't want to do this but here is how you can.

```py
def try_this(identificator, value):
    try:
       globals()[identificator] = value
       print(identificator,': ',value)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc

for item in items:
   try_this("ebay_Title",     item.title)
   try_this("ebay_Price",     item.currentPrice.value)
```

It would be better to use a predeclared object like:

```py
itemDict = {
    "ebay_Title": "",
    "ebay_Price": ""
}

def try_this(identificator, value):
    try:
       itemDict[identificator] = value
       print(identificator,': ',value)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc

for item in items:
   try_this("ebay_Title", item.title)
   try_this("ebay_Price", item.currentPrice.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the comments thread, the OP stated:

> It's a server side error, the actual function I use is a bit more complex: for item in response.reply.searchResult.item: And sometimes the server says there's not searchResult in response.reply The the code crushes – V-cash 28 mins ago

To deal with searchResult not existing, I would do this in that portion:

```
for item in getattr(response.reply, 'searchResult', []):
    ...
```

If searchResult does not exist in `response.reply`, it will return an empty list, preventing an error and making the loop do nothing.

Comment: wow if this works this could be even a better solution, I'll try it. 
Seems like Curiosity pays off very well in making you a good developer =)

Comment: when I try it i get this error `TypeError: 'ResponseDataObject' object is not iterable`

Comment: I think you will need to get a feel for what kind of object you receive from getting `'searchResult'`. It wasn't clear whether you were receiving a list within there, or a scalar value. When you get a `not iterable` error, it goes to say it's not a `list` (or `tuple`). You'll probably have a better idea of what it is by printing it out to debug it.

Comment: In other words, you could probably save the result of the `getattr` function.